# What is a Unix oneliner to swap between fields?

Tags: awk, one-liner

I have a file with a list

```
id1 str1 str2 .. strn
id2 str1 str2 .. strm
```

(the number of str can vary) and I want a oneliner that transforms it into

```
str1 str2 .. strn [id]
str1 str2 .. strm [id]
```

There should be a way with awk to do that, but I don't know how to take "all fields" after $1, when they are of variable length.

My idea would be something like

```
cat file | awk '{ print $2 and the rest " [" $1 "]" }'
```

but just missing the "$2 and the rest"....

Comment: See: [How to move first column to last column in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46546890/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s%s",$i,OFS (i==NF?"[" $1 "]" ORS:"")}' file
```

Output:

```
str1 str2 .. strn [id1]
str1 str2 .. strm [id2]
```

Answer (score 3):

### With `Perl`

```
perl -F'\s+' -E 'say join " ", @F[1..$#F], "[" . @F[0] . "]"' file
```

### Output

```
str1 str2 ... strn [id1]
str1 str2 ... strm [id2]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Like this:

```
awk '{v=$1;$1="";sub(/^ /, "");$NF=$NF" ["v"]"}1' file
```

Or exploded multi-line for readability:

```
awk '{
    v=$1
    $1=""
    sub(/^ /, "")
    $NF=$NF" ["v"]"}
    1
' file
```

### Output

```
str1 str2 ... strn [id1]
str1 str2 ... strm [id2]
```

### Explanations

| code | comment |
| --- | --- |
| `v=$1` | assign $1 in `v` variable |
| `$1=""` | unset `$1` |
| `sub(/^ /, "")` | remove leading space from `$0` |
| `$NF=$NF" ["v"]"` | append to the latest field `$NF` with expected output with id as `v` variable |
| `1` | shorthand for `print` |

Answer (score 2):

For just handling the first field then a regex based solution seems simple enough:

```bash
sed -E 's/([^[ ]+) (.*)/\2 [\1]/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone stands up and moves one space.

```
echo "a b c d e f" | awk '{ f=$1; for(i=1; i<NF; i++){ $i=$(i+1) }; $NF=f }1'
```

Output:

```
b c d e f a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{$0=$0 " [" $1 "]"; sub(/^[^ ]+ /,"")} 1' file
str1 str2 .. strn [id1]
str1 str2 .. strm [id2]
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i; print "[" $1 "]"}' file
str1 str2 .. strn [id1]
str1 str2 .. strm [id2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
id1 str1 str2 .. strn
id2 str1 str2 .. strm
```

then

```
awk '{print substr($0,index($0," ")+1),"[" $1 "]"}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
str1 str2 .. strn [id1]
str1 str2 .. strm [id2]
```

**Warning**: I assume that your values are sheared by single spaces, if this is not case do not use this solution. Explanation: I use [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to get

> $2 and the rest

by finding placement of first space (via `index` function) and than getting everything beyond that space (via `substr` function), which is then followed by 1st field value encased in `[`...`]`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Another [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) answer

```bash
perl -lane '$f = shift @F; push @F, "[$f]"; print "@F"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk` and a pattern with 2 capture groups:

```
awk 'match($0, /^([^ ]+) +(.+)/, a) {print a[2], "["a[1]"]"}' file
```

Or using POSIX bracket expressions to match spaces with `[[:space:]]`

```
gawk 'match($0, /^([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.+)/, a) {print a[2], "["a[1]"]"}' file
```

Output

```
str1 str2 .. strn [id1]
str1 str2 .. strm [id2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a very close, but whitespace agnostic substitution with `sed` using the `[[:space:]]` list in character-class to handle the whitespace regardless of whether it is `' '`, or `'\t'` or mixed using `sed` with the *extended REGEX* option would be:

```bash
sed -E 's/^([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*$)/\2 [\1]/' file
```

If your `sed` doesn't support extended regex (and doesn't use the `-r` option instead of `-E` for it), then you can do it with standard set regex by escaping the `'('` and `')'` backreference capture delimiters, e.g.

```bash
sed 's/^\([^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\(.*$\)/\2 [\1]/' file
```

(**note:** standard regex doesn't support the `'+'`, *one-or-more* occurrence, repetition operator so the `'*'` *zero-or-more* repetition is used requiring one literal match also be included to create the equivalent *one-or-more* repetition match.)

In both cases the standard substitution form is `'s/find/replace/` shown with Extended REGEX below where:

**find:**

- `^` anchors the search at the beginning of line,
- `([^[:space:]]+)` captures all (one-or-more) characters from the beginning that are not whitespace (the `'^'` in the character-class inverts the match) for use as the 1st backreference,
- `[[:space:]]+` select one or more spaces,
- `(.*$)` capture all remaining characters to `'$'` (end of line) for the 2nd backreference.

**replace**

- `\2` insert the text captured as the 2nd backreference,
- `' '` insert a space, and finally,
- `\1` insert the text captured as the 1st backreference.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*$)/\2 [\1]/' << 'eof'
id1 str1 str2 .. strn
id2 str1 str2 .. strm
eof
str1 str2 .. strn [id1]
str1 str2 .. strm [id2]
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

this should be `one-liner`- enough ?

```
echo 'id1 str1 str2 .. strn
      id2 str1 str2 .. strm' |
```

> ```
> {m,g}awk '$!NF = substr($_, index($_, $(!_+!_))) " [" $!_ "]"'
> ```

```
str1 str2 .. strn [id1]
str1 str2 .. strm [id2]
```